# The type or namespace name 'Mvc' does not exist

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

I have recently installed visual studio 2013. After downloaded a sample project from web, while i run it, it gives me the following errors-

```
The type or namespace name 'Mvc' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

How to overcome this error?

Comment: Use Nuget to add the MVC lib to your project.

Comment: @ Andrei, you suggestion works. Make it an answer so that i can accept it.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

The source of your error may be that you do not have a reference to the MVC framework library. A simple solution is to add this reference trough Nuget. The MVC library will be installed in your `bin` directory and, if needed, all the references will be added to your project.

Either browse for the MVC package (*Tools -> Nuget Package Manager -> Manage Nuget Packages for Solution*) or install it using the Nuget console (*Tools -> Nuget Package Manager -> Package Manager Console*) by entering `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc`. You can find additional information on the [official Nuget page for AspNet.Mvc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc/).

Comment: And what is this MVC framework package name, for the sake of easiness?

Comment: Make sure you select a Version that is compatible with your project .NET framework version.

Comment: @Andrei I tried your solution but I am getting the below error.                        
 install-package : Could not install package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 3.3.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 
'.NETFramework,Version=v4.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. 
For more information, contact the package author

Comment: @Andrei I managed to resolve my issue by pulling the dll reference from another project.

Answer (score 47):

My solution was to simply open up the nuget package manager console and run the command `update-package -reinstall Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc`

Comment: This solved my problem. It was working one minute then the next...nope.

Comment: This worked for me after accidentally deleting the `packages` folder

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes the package version conflict becomes an issue where if you have the MVC package installed then it shows the namespace error.

Here is how I solved it:

- Open Package Manager Console (Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console)
- Type uninstall-package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc
- Type install-package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc

So this will give your package a fresh start, you will have all new MVC references and no errors.

Answer (score 1):

Year 2022 Answer:

delete the line:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
```

and replace with:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
```

Comment: This is only the answer if you're using .Net Core. Some people still use .Net Framework.

Answer (score 0):

Including MVC controller and Model in the project resolved the issue.