# Namespace issues with ASP.NET Core 6 MVC in VS 2022

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

I have 3 controllers, 1 script, 1 utility, and 2 views that I have copied into an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC solution.

Honestly not a programmer by profession, but the platform I am developing has transitioned from ASP.NET to ASP.NET Core MVC.

I copied & revised these custom files into the build.

Aside from those, prior to now, files like settings, sitemap, web, etc. could get diffed upgrade to upgrade and not be included in the primary .dll build and function accordingly.

I diffed these files again to live within the primary .dll build this time around versus outside.

The `/Content` files like `Site.css`, `_home.scss`, I see all those now live in `wwwroot`. Those seem to be fine with the changes made in VS.

Oddly, or maybe not odd at all…none of those files sprung errors. Only the truly custom ones did.

Now I’m dealing with errors like:

> The type or namespace name 'slf4net' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

> The type or namespace name 'Mvc' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

[slf4net + mvc Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1YX8.png)

> The type or namespace name 'OutputCacheAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

> The type or namespace name 'OutputCache' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

[OutputCache](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGFHL.png)

I feel like there is likely something simple that a seasoned programmer would do to remedy this, but I have tried to research and its not really clear to me.

Any insights? All feedback is appreciated!

Comment: You are missing a using directive or an assembly reference, e.g. [slf4net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/slf4net/).

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22325964/1997232) (second error).

Comment: It's hard to understand exactly what you've got - but if you copied code from a pre-ASP.NET-Core solution into a newer one, I'm not entirely surprised that things don't work. Ultimately, to get a web app to work and be maintainable, I think you're going to have to put some time into learning how it all works - or hire someone who already understands it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does your csproj target the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` Sdk? `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">`

Comment: @Pieterjan Yes, it does. <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

Comment: @Community made edits to post, thanks!